# svn export logs

Tags: svn, logging, export

I am exporting a single file from svn, I have two questions regarding this:

a) Is it possible to get the svn export logs in xml format, just like we have for svn log & diff.

b) In svn export logs I want to check which revision number got exported. So instead of printing out "Export complete.", i want "Exported Revision xxxx". Is there an option to specify that in svn.

Thanks!

Comment: Your questions arent really related to exporting a file, you should edit the title so it more closly relates to the actual question

Answer (score 0):

You can get svn.exe to output xml using the `--xml` switch, see [this page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)

Since svn will print the logs for a bunch of revisions, it cant really do what you ask in B. however you can print the log for a specific version (see above link) and in that case you already know the revision. Also, the revisions for witch the logs are printed are included in the output, just not at the end like you describe.

-edit-

whoops you where talking about export logs, not the svn log command, sorry, my bad.

still some of my awnser is kinda applicable, you can specify the revision to export and by doing that know what revision is exported. to my knowledge, there is no way to output the export log as xml. you can however use svn list and log to get the same information